# Projecting a photo as a texture onto a model in SketchUp?

Tags: sketchup

SketchUp has many third party tools and add-ons, so my question is if there is already a tool to do the following task.

Let's say I'm modeling a building project and I have the 3D-model done. Then the actual construction takes place and I have some photos of the project being partially done. So I take one of the photos and match the 3D-model camera view to it exactly. I want then for the photo to be projected onto the visible 3D-scene as a texture. Obviously, so that I could then move the scene/camera to a degree, while preserving some resemblance of how it actually looks in real world.

Is there already a solution to make it possible?

Comment: I know this is possible in zbrush, however my comment won't be useful unless you'd consider using sketchup in conjunction with zbrush. this is how it's done in zbrush https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFkh0dl85GU . you can export polypaint as albedo texture and reimport it into sketchup.

Comment: note that you'd have to have the model UV mapped before exporting it for zbrush, so that texture map works in sketchup when you bring it.

Comment: @Lilith thank you, that actually looks very useful, even better than I thought since you can move the model and the photo as you go painting it though for the best match. At least for the presentation purposes it's a viable way, though I assume reimporting it back into SketchUp will be a pain and not really compatible with the layered and grouped structure of the project.

Comment: you can actually render in zbrush. this way, you won't have to reimport into sketchup. zbrush is not the best rendering solution, but does an okay job if you don't need photorealism etc. example vid; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM-VonmG0jU